# Convert consecutive bytes in array to a pointer without using shift

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have an 2d array that contains an address. The address starts at `code[line][1]`. It's 4 bytes long. I need to convert this to a pointer without using shift.

Below is the code I use with shifts and it works fine. If I can get these bytes into a `long` that will work since I can convert the `long` into the pointer. Also if the bytes are in the wrong order I can change my code somewhere else to get the correct endian style. No function calls.

Trying to search for examples on this is hard because they all show how to do it with shifts.

```
unsigned long address = (((unsigned long) code[line][1]) << 24) +
                        (((unsigned long) code[line][2]) << 16) +
                        (((unsigned long) code[line][3]) << 8) +
                        code[line][4];
unsigned int *add = (unsigned int*) address;
```

Comment: This is the preferred way of performing a conversion like this.  Why don't you want to use shifts?

Comment: im on a micro.. and im doing some self programming stuff and using shift calls functions that would not be available.. there has to be a way to do it without shifts..

Comment: If you don't care about portable code and you know the endianness of your system, you can just copy the bytes one-by-one using a `char*` It's ugly but it will work (on your specific system)

Comment: I find it pretty strange that your index runs from 1 to 4. I would expect 0 to 3.

Comment: You can multiply by appropriate powers of 2 instead of shifting.

Comment: the subarray is 17 bytes long...[0] contains other data... as well as [5]+.

Comment: Looks like an XY problem or a bad design. Did you profile the shifts? Check the assembler code? Use optimisation? etc.

Answer (score 1):

In embedded systems with small processors and a system (i.e. compiler, os, etc.) that are very unlikely to change for the life time of a project, it can make sense to make non-portable code. In other words: code that can run on this system but is likely to fail on others.

If you don't care about portability, you can simply copy the bytes from `code[line][x]` directly into the final pointer. Note that it requires use of correct endianness and use of correct pointer size.

Something like this (assuming a 4 byte pointer and assuming `code` contains bytes):

```
unsigned int* add;
char* tmp = (char*)&add;

tmp[0] = code[line][4];
tmp[1] = code[line][3];
tmp[2] = code[line][2];
tmp[3] = code[line][1];

// Now you can use add as a pointer
```

If your system has the opposite endianness, just start with index 1 and end with index 4.

Once again - this is non-portable code.

Comment: You are aware OP uses an MSP430? Your code invokes undefined behaviour for two causes!

Comment: @Olaf - No, I did not see MSP430 mentioned in the question. BTW - please explain the two causes for UB

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39149907/convert-consecutive-bytes-in-array-to-a-pointer-without-using-shift/39150726?noredirect=1#comment65645948_39150945

Comment: One is founded in the arch and a wrong assumption on your side. The other for violating effective type rule. See the standard. The compiler should warn about the code for good reasons.

Comment: @Olaf - Thanks, very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I think I got it..

```
add = (unsigned int*) (*((unsigned long*) &code[line][1]));
```

i took pointer to the first byte and cast it to long pointer... then take the value of the long can cast it to a int pointer.. had to change my endian

Comment: its working on msp430.. portability is not a concern

Comment: It may work on your specific system but violate `strict aliasing` rule, i.e. unexpected compiler optimizations may break your code

Comment: This invokes undefined behaviour. I'd not bet a cent (US or Euro) on this working reliably. Use the shifts and a modern compiler, e.g. gcc.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a union. Something like this:

```
union un{
    char bytes[4]; //assuming the size of the array is [x][4]
    int* address;
};
un code[numLines];
```

You might have to move some stuff around a little. This would be like using code[line][0] through [3] instead of code[line][1] through [4]

Also, make sure the endianness of your system works with this method.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an `union`!

```
union {
    char ch[4];
    unsigned int *ptr;
} add;

add.ch[0] = code[line][4];
add.ch[1] = code[line][3];
add.ch[2] = code[line][2];
add.ch[3] = code[line][1];
```

Comment: You are aware OP uses an MSP430? Your code invokes undefined behaviour!

Comment: @Olaf: No, i was not aware that a MSP430 is used. May you explain me, why my code invokes undefined behaviour?